# How to model in postgres an array that has objects, each object has a String for title and a sub-array of strings

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have the following format in json to store **lawyers**, I have doubts how to model in postgres the field "specialties" which has array of object each one with a title and a subarrays of subspecialties:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Johnson Johannes",
  "gender": "f",
  "specialties": [
    {
      "specialty": "Business law",
      "sub-specialties": [
        "Incorporation",
        "Taxes",
        "Fusions"
      ]
    },
        {
      "specialty": "Criminal law",
      "sub-specialties": [
        "Property offenses",
        "Personal offenses",
        "Strict liability"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have made this lawyers table in Postgres:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lawyers_db;
CREATE DATABASE lawyers_db;

\c lawyers_db;

CREATE TYPE gen AS ENUM ('f', 'm');

CREATE TABLE lawyers_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  gender gen
);

INSERT INTO lawyers_tb (name, gender)
  VALUES ('John Doe', 'm');
```

I'm using some node.js libraries that when I read data from Postgres table it returns the data as a JSON, so I would like to keep the relational model without using JSONb to store as a document my lawyers.

Is it possible to achieve what I want without using JSONb type?

Comment: You cannot be using 9.2, 9.3 and 9.4 at the same time. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about objects for a minute and really think through what your data are and how they relate to each other (we are after all using a relational database).

What you have here is simply a relationship.

You have lawyers and you have specialties. The relationship is that lawyers have specialties and specialties belong to lawyers (an n-to-n relationship) and the same goes for the relationship between specialties and subspecialties (n-to-n).

First, lets do the simpler structure of a 1-to-n relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyers_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  gender gen
);

CREATE TABLE specialties_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  lawyer_ID INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE subspecialties_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  specialty_ID INTEGER
);
```

This works but results in duplicates because each specialty can only belong to one lawyer thus if two lawyers specialise in "Business law" you'd have to define "Business law" twice. Worse, for each specialty you also have to duplicate subspecialties.

The solution is a join table (also called a map/mapping table):

```
CREATE TABLE lawyers_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  gender gen
);

CREATE TABLE lawyer_specialties_tb (
  name VARCHAR,
  lawyer_ID INTEGER,
  specialty_ID INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE specialties_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE specialty_subspecialties_tb (
  name VARCHAR,
  specialty_ID INTEGER,
  subspecialty_ID INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE subspecialties_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);
```

This way each specialty can belong to more than one lawyer (true n-to-n relationship) and each subspecialty can belong to more than one specialty.

You can use joins to fetch the whole dataset:

```
SELECT lawyers_tb.name as name,
       lawyers_tb.gender as gender,
       specialties_tb.name as specialty,
       subspecialties_tb.name as subspecialty
FROM lawyers_tb LEFT JOIN lawyer_specialties_tb
         ON lawyers_tb.ID=lawyer_specialties_tb.lawyer_ID
     LEFT JOIN specialties_tb
         ON specialties_tb.ID=lawyer_specialties_tb.specialty_ID
     LEFT JOIN specialty_subspecialties_tb
         ON specialties_tb.ID=specialty_subspecialties_tb.specialty_ID
```

Yes, it's a bit more complicated to query but the structure allows you to maintain each dataset individually and defines the proper relationships between them.

You may also want to define the keys in the join tables as foreign keys to enforce correctness of the dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Is the script for `lawyer_specialties_tb` correct? I don't understand the need for 3 different ids in that tb? Also shouldnt `lawyer_ID` be a foreign key?

Comment: Ah. Yeah. I copy pasted. I'll fix it.

Comment: And yes, the keys in the join tables should be defined as foreign keys to enforce referential integrity. But that doesn't affect the structure or the query.

Comment: what is the **concept/name** of `lawyer_specialties_tb` and `specialty_subspecialties_tb` they seem to be just a glue/link between the other tables. I would like to learn more about this concept to really understand this

Comment: I mentioned them in the answer: join tables (also sometimes called map table or mapping table)